# nginx forward to certain apache port on the basis of cookie

Tags: php, apache, cookies, nginx, webserver

**Problem statement**: I have two versions of my website (LAMP) and have to run both versions simultaneously. i.e. both versions have to be displayed to users on the basis of certain cookie.

**web servers**: nginx first level, apache second level.

**Solution which I have thought**: Request will reach to nginx at first level and nginx on the basis of cookie will decide on which apache port it has to be forwarded, and on the basis of port, mapped virtual host will be executed.

nginx configuration: I will configure nginx like request will be forwarded to certain apache port on the basis of cookie.

apache configuration: will create two virtual hosts with different web roots. Now I want to configure apache such as my two virtual hosts will be running on different ports.

**Is the above solution feasible?** If yes, then how can I configure my nginx on the basis of cookie which will be forwarded to certain apache port? Any other solution which can help me maintaining two different versions of the website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeeded doing it.

nginx configuration:

```
 server {
    listen       80;
    server_name example.com;
    location /
    {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-FORWARDED_PROTO https;
        if ($http_cookie ~ 'ver=1' ) {
            proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:6060;
        }
        if ($http_cookie ~ 'ver=2' ) {
            proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:7070;
        }
    }
}
```

apache configuration:

```
Listen 6060
Listen 7070

    <VirtualHost *:6060>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/ver1/
        ServerName example.com
    </VirtualHost>
    <VirtualHost *:7070>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/ver2/
        ServerName example.com
    </VirtualHost>
```